# Serve static site on S3 + CloudFlare with Apache retaining the source URL

Tags: apache, amazon-s3, cloudflare, cdn

I have React app on S3 with CDN as CloudFlare(abc-apps.com). My main tomcat application is running on EC2 with Apache as a webserver fronted by ALB and DNS(abc.com) hosted on CloudFlare. Now I want my tomcat applications's domain with subpath abc.com/foo to redirect to the CDN(abc-apps.com) without replacing the URL in the browser and serve the content from S3 via CloudFlare.

To achieve that I have added the following to my Apache config:

```
  ProxyPass /foo https://abc-apps.com/a/b flushpackets=Off keepalive=Off timeout=600

  ProxyPassReverse /foo https://abc-apps.com/a/b
```

I have also tried with RewriteCond and RewriteRule, which works but, replaces the URL in the browser with https://abc-apps.com/a/b.

This is what it returns when the site abc.com/foo is hit with the current ProxyPass config in Apache.

[image]

**I was able to achieve the expected result with CloudFront by adding abc.com as an "alternate domain" to CloudFront, but the same can't be done with CloudFlare**

Comment: "Now I want my tomcat applications's domain with subpath abc.com/foo to redirect to the CDN(abc-apps.com) without replacing the URL in the browser and serve the content from S3 via CloudFlare."  You sure you want that?  It's not generally wise to put your own server in front of a cdn.

Comment: "Now I want my tomcat applications's domain with subpath abc.com/foo to redirect to the CDN(abc-apps.com) without replacing the URL in the browser" By definition a redirect is an HTTP response that instructs the web browser to go to a different URL (replacing the URL in the browser). So what you describe cannot exist since that's simply not how redirects work. It sounds like you want a subpath of your tomcat app to be "proxied" to your static site, not redirected.

Comment: @MarkB, can you please share the config sample on how I can set this up